# Retrieve Docker image tags from a 3rd party repo

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-api

For Docker images that come straight from Docker Hub, I can retrieve the current list of tags for an image by hitting their repository API. For example, `https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/python/tags` will give me a list of tags that can be used with `docker pull python:<tag>`.

For Elastic Search, I'm using their official repository and can pull an image using something like `docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.0`

However, I can't figure out how to pull a list of tags from that repository. I've tried

```
https://docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tags
https://docker.elastic.co/v1/repositories/elasticsearch
https://docker.elastic.co/v2/repositories/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/_manifests/tags
```

..and several other variations. What URL/API endpoints is the docker command line tool translating that repository/image name into on the backend request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `docker.elastic.co` is running a V2 docker registry, so it requires V2 API commands and token authentication. Trying to initially get the tags results in a 401 with information on how to get the token:

```
http https://docker.elastic.co/v2/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tags/list                                                                                                                       (566ms)  
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 170
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 09 May 2019 15:24:42 GMT
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://docker-auth.elastic.co/auth",service="token-service",scope="repository:elasticsearch/elasticsearch:pull"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
            "detail": [
                {
                    "Action": "pull",
                    "Class": "",
                    "Name": "elasticsearch/elasticsearch",
                    "Type": "repository"
                }
            ],
            "message": "authentication required"
        }
    ]
}
```

Use the information in the `WWW-Authenticate` to request a token for the given `service` and `scope`:

```
http "https://docker-auth.elastic.co/auth?service=token-service&scope=repository:elasticsearch/elasticsearch:pull"                                                                            (567ms)  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 790
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 09 May 2019 15:25:37 GMT

{
    "token": "some-long-token"
}
```

Finally, make the request using the token:

```
http -v https://docker.elastic.co/v2/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tags/list 'Authorization: Bearer some-long-token'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1765
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 09 May 2019 15:26:18 GMT
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{
    "name": "elasticsearch/elasticsearch",
    "tags": [
        "5.0.0-731e78df",
        "5.0.0-86a0b164",
        "5.0.0-alpha5",
        "5.0.0-beta1",
        "5.0.0-ccd69424",
        "5.0.0-rc1",
        "5.0.0",
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same way how you did for python to get the tags / list of versions available.

example : https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/elasticsearch/tags

sample Outp : `[{"layer": "", "name": "1"}, {"layer": "", "name": "1-alpine"}]`

So what you are trying to do , you will provide a provision / show list of tags in a shell script and ask them to opt . Then based on that you will do the docker pull and run those commands in your custom Docker FIle ?

Comment: That isn't the same repository. When you do a pull from docker.elastic.co, it uses docker.elastic.co, not hub.docker.com.

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer above.

Comment: thats great to hear, because of this suggestion only i mentioned to pull the image list from docker hub. Because they kept mirroring those elastic related images (don't think all elastic docker images :) ) . Ref: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/89